URL as dynamic path is being overriden
I am using Next JS App Router and am trying to have a url be the path. For example, https://mywebsite.com/https://another-url.com. The issue I am having is that whenever I input the url into my browser it gets converted to https://mywebsite.com/https:/another-url.com. Is there an easy way to fix this? I am pretty sure this is a project issue because when I do https://google.com/https://another-url.com, it does not get converted to https://google.com/https:/another-url.com.
